# Problema con vista de diseño activity main drawer

Tags: android-studio, vistas

Por favor, alguien me puede ayudar con esto? Tengo un navigation drawer en el que no se carga la vista diseño activity_main drawer.xml, sólo carga la vista txt, el resto de los xml cargan ok. Me aparece un error choclazo de java null pointer exception, aunque la aplicación funciona bien y no me muestra errores de build. Gracias[image: ![en la vista design se queda así y no hace nada]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbwqp.png) [[image: la vista text se ve ok]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKjC8.png) [[image: me sale este error, pero compila y funciona ok]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B57M.png)

Comment: Brenda en la mayoría de las ocasiones esto esta relacionado con la memoria, asegura cerrar aplicaciones que no necesites, cierra el layout reinicia la IDE y abre nuevamente el layout, comenta que obtienes.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, encontraste la solución ?

Comment: Mira, lo que hice fue bajar la versión min del sdk dentro de gradle.app y la target version en vez de ponerla en 27 la puse en 26 y funcionó.